# Infinite loop while reading from pipe

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me why I have an infinite loop when reading from a pipe? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. `message` is the name I defined in main top refer to it. MESSAGE is my struct name. It doesn't even print out test value.

```
if(manager_pid == 0)
{
    printf("Hello? \n");
    if(close(pipe1[READING]) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error in closing pipe1 \n");
    }
    if(close(pipe2[READING]) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error in closing pipe2 \n");
    }
    if(close(pipe3[WRITING]) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error in closing pipe \n");
    }
}
i = 0;
printf("work please \n");
//test_value = read(pipe3[READING], &boo, sizeof(echo));
//printf("test_value is %d \n", test_value);

while(i < 10)
{
    printf("In while \n");
    //printf("Hello?? \n");
    //test_value = read(pipe3[READING], &boo, sizeof(echo));
    //printf("test_value is %d \n", test_value);
    //printf("Entering infinite loop \n");
    //printf("i is %d \n", i);
    //nbytes = read(pipe3[0], array, 45);
    //printf("nbytes is %d \n", nbytes);
    //log_dat_fp = fopen(argv[2], "a");
    if(read(pipe3[READING], &message, sizeof(struct MESSAGE)) != -1)
    {
        printf("Entering if \n");
        log_dat_fp = fopen(argv[2], "a");
        printf("First if  \n");
        time(&current_time);
        //if(message.owner == 1 && (message.instruction == 'r' || message.instruction == 'R'))
        if(message.instruction == 'r' || message.instruction == 'R')
        {
            if(message.owner == 1)
            {
                printf("message.owner == 1 with r or R \n");
                fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s received message %d %d %c %s", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                message.owner, getpid(), message.instruction, message.id);
                pclose(log_dat_fp);
            }
            else if(message.owner == 2)
            {
                printf("message.owner == 2 with r or R  \n");
                fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s received message %d %d %c %s", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                message.owner, getpid(), message.instruction, message.id);
                pclose(log_dat_fp);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You have junk  \n");
            }
        }
        else if(message.instruction == 'u' || message.instruction == 'U')
        {
            if(message.owner == 1)
            {
                printf("message.owner == 1 with u or U  \n");
                fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s received message %d %d %c %s %d", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                message.owner, getpid(), message.instruction, message.id, message.value);
                pclose(log_dat_fp);
            }
            else if(message.owner == 2)
            {
                printf("message.owner == 2 with u or U  \n");
                fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s received message %d %d %c %s %d", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                message.owner, getpid(), message.instruction, message.id, message.value);
                pclose(log_dat_fp);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You have junk  \n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("manager can't read from pipe\n");
            exit(1);
        } // read no good
        if(message.instruction == 'r' || message.instruction == 'R')
        {
            if(message.owner == 1)
            {
                for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(storage, table[i].id) == 0)
                    {
                        match_flag = 1;
                        value = table[i].value;
                    }
                }
                if(match_flag == 1)
                {
                    message.value = value;
                    message.owner = 0;
                    if(write(pipe1[WRITING], &message, sizeof(struct MESSAGE)) == sizeof(struct MESSAGE))
                    {
                        log_dat_fp = fopen(argv[2], "a");
                        time(&current_time);
                        fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s sent message: %c %d %s %d\n", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                        message.instruction, message.owner, message.id, message.value);
                        fclose(log_dat_fp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("error returning message to process 1");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                else
                    message.owner = 1;
                    if(write(pipe1[WRITING], &message, sizeof(struct MESSAGE)) == sizeof(struct MESSAGE))
                    {
                        log_dat_fp = fopen(argv[2], "a");
                        time(&current_time);
                        fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s sent message: %c %d %s \n", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                        message.instruction, message.owner, message.id);
                        fclose(log_dat_fp);
                    }

            }
            else if(message.owner == 2)
            {
                printf("message.owner == 2 with u or U  \n");
                fprintf(log_dat_fp, "Store Manager at time: %s received message %d %d %c %s %d", strtok(ctime(&current_time), "\n"), 
                message.owner, getpid(), message.instruction, message.id, message.value);
                pclose(log_dat_fp);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You have junk  \n");
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("manager had pipe issues.\n");
        exit(1);
    }// read no good
    i++;
    //log_dat_fp = fopen(argv[2], "a");
    printf("Each pass  \n");
}
```

Comment: who is writing to the pipe? is your parent process doing that?

Comment: You're not checking for partial reads or EOF.

Comment: @RADAR another one my processes will later on `write(pipe3r[writing], &message, sizeof(struct MESSAGE))`. I was trying to figure out why I have an infinite loop first. It doesn't seem like it is even reading. My printf is completely ignored so I think I have issues with this `printf("test_value is %d \n", test_value);`.

Comment: @o11c how do I do that?

Comment: It is stuck in read call reading for the data, unless you writ to the pipe , it will wait there

Comment: But shouldn't this print statement have some value `printf("test_value is %d \n", test_value);`? It completely ignores it.

Comment: this line: test_value = read(pipe3[READING], &message, sizeof(struct MESSAGE)); has already read the message from the pipe and test_value is actually the status of the read() where, if the read was successful, it will contain the number bytes read.

Comment: if the sender (writer) is not sending two messages, the second read will hang, forever.  However, the prefered method for reading from a pipe is to set the pipe send and recv ends to non-blocking, the read characters (usually one by one) progressively into a buffer, like message, until the buffer is full, then check for 'magic' number (part of the sent message) and shift the message until the magic number aligns with its' location in the message buffer, reading more bytes to keep the buffer full.

Comment: 1) As @radar says, code is in `read(pipe3[READING],` waiting. 2) `stdout` is somehow closed.  Write test message to `stderr`. 3) Someplace memory is corrupt or  UB.  4) Want `pread()` vs. `read()`?

Comment: @user3629249 Is this what you are referring to? `    if(manager_pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Hello? \n");
        if(close(pipe1[READING]) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in closing pipe1 \n");
        }
        if(close(pipe2[READING]) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in closing pipe2 \n");
        }
        if(close(pipe3[WRITING]) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error in closing pipe \n");
        }
    }`

Comment: @RADAR Can you please take another look at this? I am now writing and still have infinite loop.

Comment: @user3629249 Can you please take another look at this? I am now writing and still have infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
function returns 0 on EOF, not -1.  Since you test for the wrong condition, you get an infinite loop.

Note that the description says:

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, `read()` shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file.
> - If some process has the pipe open for writing and `O_NONBLOCK` is set, `read()` shall return -1 and set `errno` to `[EAGAIN]`.
> - If some process has the pipe open for writing and `O_NONBLOCK` is clear, `read()` shall block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe open for writing.

Reading zero bytes because there are no bytes to read is success.  That is how EOF is indicated by `read()`, whether it is on a file or any other device type.  Terminals are a special case; they may return 0 bytes after you type (on Unix) <kbd>control-D</kbd>, and then a retry may return extra data typed after that.  Once upon a long time ago, tape drives were somewhat similar.  But when `read()` returns 0, there is (for the time being) no more data to read.  For a pipe, that means all writers closed their write file descriptor.