# Loop doesn't finish when reading from pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I'm following the free book [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) by Arpaci-Dusseau, and despite being very new to C programming (constructive criticism is welcomed), I tried my luck on coding problem 8 from chapter 5:

> Write a program that creates two children, and connects the standard
> output of one to the standard input of the other, using the `pipe()`
> system call.

Here is my attempt (some error-checking is removed for brevity):

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipefd[2];
    char buf;

    pipe(pipefd);

    int rc1 = fork();
    if (rc1 == 0) {
        // Child 1, reading from argv, writing to pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(pipefd[1]);
        printf("Child 1 done.\n");
    } else {
        // Parent
        wait(NULL);
        int rc2 = fork();
        if (rc2 == 0) {
            // Child 2, reading from pipe, writing to stdout
            printf("Entering child 2\n");
            close(pipefd[1]);
            while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
            }
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
            printf("Wrote to stdout!\n");
            close(pipefd[0]);
            printf("Child 2 done.\n");
        } else {
            // Still parent
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Parent finished running.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

which generates the following output, and hangs:

```
$ ./myprogram "Hello world"
Child 1 done.
Entering child 2
Hello world█
```

where `█` is the shell cursor, i.e. the `while` loop hasn't exited to reach the writing of the newline character thereafter.

I ***did***, however, get this to work by replacing `char buf;` with `char buf[1024];` and the lines

```c
while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
}
```

with

```c
int n = read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1024);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n);
```

So, now it works. But I don't understand why the previous version did *not* work. That reading loop was practically identical to the one used in the example at the bottom of the [`pipe(2)` man-pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), which I have verified to be working correctly for me. But why doesn't it work in my own little program?

Possible duplicate questions:
([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955487/program-doesnt-stop-after-reading-from-pipe)) Solution is to close unused ends of pipe. I believe I have done that correctly.
([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685279/infinite-loop-while-reading-from-pipe)) Solution is to break on return codes `<= 0`, not on `< 0`. I believe I have done that correctly too.

Comment: What happens if you add a delay in the first child process, so it starts writing (and more importantly closes the pipe) after the second child process have started?

Comment: Also note that if `buf` is still a single character, then `read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1024)` will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, right now I am explicitly `wait`ing for child 1 to finish before forking a new one. I wanted to be sure child 1 finished writing before attempting to read from the pipe. But when I remove the `wait` and add a `sleep` to child 1, as you say, then it does work, yes! What is this magic?

Comment: Or... well... it prints my debug-prints in a weird order, but at least it finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pipefd[1])` never gets closed in the original parent process.  So `read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1)` will hang in the second child process.

This version

```
int n = read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1024);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, n);
```

doesn't hang because there's no loop.  The second child process reads the data written by

```
write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

and then continues onward, never checking `pipefd[0]` again.  So it doesn't matter if `read(pipefd[0],...)` *would* hang.